# Flex display conflicts with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I have these buttons in a `div` and their css as follows:

```css
div {
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
div.IFlexible {
    display:flex;    
}
div.yesno {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4vw;
}
div > button{
    font-size: 5vw;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="yesno IFlexible">
    <button id="addNewOK" class="confirmBut">Confirm</button>
    <button id="addNewCancel" class="confirmBut">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

And there is nothing else that would concern these buttons.

My intention was to have the buttons at the bottom of the screen, while stretching them to take up even space and take up all the space. Question is, how do I do it?

Comment: would column CSS will do ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZXXGBz

Comment: Are asking if I would rather layout my buttons one on top of another?

Comment: nop, just look at the codepen if that is what you try to do... i'll make an answer so you can see here too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed the `flex-grow` property to `flex` and added the `width` of `100%` to the `div.IFlexible`:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}
html, body {width: 100%}

div {
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div.IFlexible {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%; /* added */
}

div.yesno {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4vw;
}

div > button {
  font-size: 5vw;
  flex: 1; /* modified */
}
```

```html
<div class="yesno IFlexible">
  <button id="addNewOK" class="confirmBut">Confirm</button>
  <button id="addNewCancel" class="confirmBut">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use multiple column css https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/

```css
div {
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
div.IFlexible {
    column-count:2;
      
}
div.yesno {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4vw;
  left:4vw;
  right:4vw;
}
div > button{
    font-size: 5vw;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="yesno IFlexible">
    <button id="addNewOK" class="confirmBut">Confirm</button>
    <button id="addNewCancel" class="confirmBut">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

you may also use display:grid;

```css
div {
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
div.IFlexible {
    display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap:4vw
      
}
div.yesno {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4vw;
  left:4vw;
  right:4vw;
}
div > button{
    font-size: 5vw;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="yesno IFlexible">
    <button id="addNewOK" class="confirmBut">Confirm</button>
    <button id="addNewCancel" class="confirmBut">Cancel</button>
  
</div>
```

You actually only need to size the container , via coordonates will be easier than width:

```css
div {
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
div.IFlexible {
    display:flex;    
}
div.yesno {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4vw;
  left:1vw;
  right:1vw;
}
div > button{
    font-size: 5vw;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="yesno IFlexible">
    <button id="addNewOK" class="confirmBut">Confirm</button>
    <button id="addNewCancel" class="confirmBut">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It certainly worths noting for future reference. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @agiro you also have display:table/grid aside flex

Comment: Yes, though in a tutorial I watched (made by Pluralsight) I heard tables aren't the proper way to format a website. I don't know why, but I figured if their expert says so, I rather avoid learning some bad practice. I'm more accustomed to WPF layout meself though (where grid rules), this stuff is a whole new world to me. As far as I believe though grids are awesome in these cases. If I get skilled enough to have an understanding, I might use them anyway :D

Comment: @agiro **oh my god!!** , display is CSS, not HTML . The good practice is to learn to use the proper tag for their semantic, and style via the CSS. so when you tell a div not to display as a block but as flex or table or grid or list-item ... it will remain a DIV and neutral for ever ....

Comment: Or I just misunderstood something they said. By the way, your grid layout was handy just now for another set of elements, so once again thank you for sharing it!

Comment: @agiro maybe this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ and https://gridbyexample.com/examples/ will be usefull when you have sometimes to dig into the grid display ;)

Comment: heh that's some well-made website. Will definitely bookmark that one :D

Answer (score 0):

You can force the buttons to take up the full width (50% of space per each button) by specifying a 50% width to each button and a 100% width to the div that they're inside.

```
div {
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
div.IFlexible {
    display:flex;
    width: 100%;
}
div.yesno {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4vw;
}
div > button{
    font-size: 5vw;
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 50%
}
```

Hope this helps